# How to add 2 instances of the same Fragment to backstack

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a fragment A, in this fragment I have a Webview load content dynamic from an URL and a button to load next URL.
The scenario is like below:


Fragment A (url-1)-----(click button next)-----> Fragment A (url-2)-----(click button next)-----> Fragment A (url-3)


Each time I add fragment to content frame, I also add it to Backstack.
But when I back from 3rd or 2nd Fragment A, the previous Fragment always dont display Webview content that already displayed before move to next Fragment.

The question is: could I add multiple dynamic fragment to backstack continuously?
How to keep my dynamic content not disappear after back from backstack?

My sample code is here, plz take a look bros:
http://pastebin.com/CG12a2sz

Comment: Are you replacing or adding fragments? And share your code also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found my problem is using Fragment with ViewPagerFragmentAdapter inside it.
It is seen as an Android bug that not fixed by  Gooogle. I resolved it by changed to using Activity not Fragment.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply use WebView goBack() method?

Comment: I just use this to be sample, what I mean is a dynamic content when fragment init.

Comment: Well in theory what you are doing is not wrong. Could you share your code? Probably something else is wrong

Comment: The problem is that you are using add here.
You should do something like
fragmentTransaction.replace(...);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
fragmentTransaction.commit();